# Mongodb cluster:can query on normal collections ,but not on system.users

Tags: mongodb, authentication, admin, roles

I use keyFile to authenticate my mongodb cluster system.I have already had an administrator role against **admin** db:

So , at first I login with authentication:

```
mongo localhost:40000/admin -u root -p 123456
mongos> use admin
switched to db admin
mongos> db.system.users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52dcb305398751501c530378"), "user" : "root", "pwd" : "a02786431d8419bbebee7aa4dad6aee9", "roles" : [  "clusterAdmin",  "userAdmin",  "readWriteAnyDatabase",  "dbAdmin",  "read" ] }
```

After I log in with such a role ,I can do any thing(including query,delete,modify and so on) on admin and any other normal databases except for addUser operation!

For example, for a normal database **genbank** ,I tried to add a user :

```
mongos> use genbank
switched to db genbank
mongos> db.addUser({user:"genbankReader",pwd:"123456",roles:["read"]})
{
        "user" : "genbankReader",
        "pwd" : "6f755264f6d28045198f6ae53523005e",
        "roles" : [
                "read"
        ],
        "_id" : ObjectId("52dcb8495ec4b673f09b66eb")
}
Mon Jan 20 13:46:49.007 couldn't add user: not authorized for insert on genbank.system.users at src/mongo/shell/db.js:128
```

But for database admin ,I can do addUser() as I want:

```
mongos> use admin
switched to db admin
mongos> db.addUser({user:"adminReader",pwd:"123456",roles:["read"]})
{
        "user" : "adminReader",
        "pwd" : "60c67cf3181b8b8570583ddfb62dd32e",
        "roles" : [
                "read"
        ],
        "_id" : ObjectId("52dcb8b25ec4b673f09b66ec")
}
```

It is really strange!

Answer (score 0):

After I change the root roles from

```
[  "clusterAdmin",  "userAdmin",  "readWriteAnyDatabase",  "dbAdmin",  "read" ]
```

to

```
[ "clusterAdmin", "userAdminAnyDatabase",  "dbAdminAnyDatabase", "readWriteAnyDatabase" ]
```

,problem solved!

It seems that the problem comes from the role type "userAdmin".From [mongodb doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/) , the user admin role against db admin is the same as userAdminAnyDatabase:

```
Note The userAdmin role is a database-specific privilege, and only grants a user the ability to administer users on a single database. However, for the admin database, userAdmin **allows a user the ability to gain userAdminAnyDatabase**. Thus, for the admin database only, these roles are effectively the same.
```

So , the  role type userAdmin against database admin doesn't provide us directly the ability to administer users on other dbs , but user under this role can create another role 'userAdminAnyDatabase' and only under this can user administer other db's users.